# IIS FTP cannot connect, 421 Service not available error

Tags: iis, amazon-ec2, ftp

IIS FTP server stopped accepting connections, returning a "421 Service not avaialble, remote server has closed connection." error message after the instance was rebooted. The problem does not appear to be a firewall issue.

I had set up an IIS FTP server on an EC2 instance running Windows Server 2012 R2. Very basic, my boss just wanted plain FTP. I had previously set up an SFTP server on the same instance, using Cygwin sshd, that was working just fine. I set up the "default" IIS FTP server, and it was working fine for a few days, until during a file transfer, it hung. The CPU was pegged at 100%, according to the AWS monitor. I could not RDP into the instance, so I had to re-boot it. Ever since, I could not connect to the IIS FTP server. The "ftpsvc" process status is running, according to the task manager. I have stopped and started it several times. The Windows firewall is off, the AWS firewall has ports 20, 21, and 50,000-51,000 open. No settings, that I am aware of, have changed since it stopped working.

From a local command prompt:

```
> ftp localhost
Connected to MYINSTANCE
Connection closed by remote host.
```

From a remote command prompt:

```
$ ftp myact@xx.xx.xx.xx
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx
421 Service not available, remote server has closed connection.
```

But SFTP works:

```
$sftp myact@xx.xx.xx.xx
myact@xx.xx.xx.xx's password: ****
Connected to xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I am not very familiar with IIS, and it seems to be running but I don't understand why FTP stopped working after the instance reboot. Note that the EC2 instance is using an Elastic IP, so its at the same public IP address as before the problem started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem turned out to be an incorrect setting in the IIS FTP-site Site Bindings. EC2 instances have 2 IP addresses, one private and one public. It seems that the FTP server was set with the EC2 instance private IP address, and when the instance re-booted, it got a different private IP, but was re-assigned the same public IP using the Elastic IP feature. Live and learn.

Comment: Does this mean that one cannot set `127.0.0.1' or `localhost' as FTP-site Site Bindings?

Comment: I think that localhost would not be visible outside of the machine, so I don't see why you would ever set the FTP site binding to that. I was just running the ftp localhost command to test the server. But I have never tried to set site binding to that, you normally want to use the public IP address.

Comment: In `Binding and SSL` section of my EC2 win server 2012, `All Unassigned` did not work, however, private (not elastic IP) worked. So, I thought, every time I reboot the instance, I will need to reset the private IP.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post here because this was a big headache for me too.  I had to add svchost.exe to the windows firewall and everything worked.

http://youtu.be/l_sk5ITlICo?t=4m53s

Comment: thank you very much @Alex it save my time